# Pandas get count of value stored in an array in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame where one of the columns is an array of keywords, one row in the data frame would look like

id, jobtitle, company, url, keywords

1, Software Engineer, Facebook, http://xx.xx, [javascript, java, python]

However the number of possible keywords can range from 1 to 40

But I would like to do some data analysis like,

1. what keyword appears most often across the whole dataset
2. what keywords appear most often for each job title/company

Apart from giving each keyword its own column and dealing with lots of NAN values is there an easy way to answer these questions with python, (permeably pandas as its a dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
import pandas as pd

keyword_dict = {}
def count_keywords(keyword):

    for item in keyword:
        if item in keyword_dict:
            keyword_dict[item] += 1
        else:
            keyword_dict[item] =1

def new_function():
    data = {'keywords':
            [['hello', 'test'], ['test', 'other'], ['test', 'hello']]
            }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.keywords.map(count_keywords)
    
    print(keyword_dict)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_function()
```

output

```
{'hello': 2, 'test': 3, 'other': 1}
```

Comment: I changed it from job title to keywords as that is what I want to expand however that always returns an empty set, here is a screenshot of one of the rows from the dataframe 
https://snipboard.io/mQLDjr.jpg

Comment: Are you storing a list in the keyword column ?

Comment: I believe so, type(df.loc[0]['keywords']) returns a list

Comment: Ok - what I wrote above likely won't work with a string, that's made more for a string of text. One thing I have done in the past is map that column and add the words to a dictionary and increment the values for each occurrence. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I appreciate the help, this worked just as I had hoped